# Convergence of empirical average of Markov chain from transient class

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, ergodic-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I am trying to get an intuition of how to understand the limit of the empirical average
$$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\tag{$\ast$}$$
of some Markov chain $(X_n)_n$ with transition matrix $P$ (let's assume finite dimensional for simplicity).

Let $C_1,\ldots,C_m$ be the communicating classes of $(X_n)$.

If the process starts from recurrent (and thus closed) class $C_i$, then the Ergodic Theorem (see Thm 1.10.2 [here](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s110.pdf)) gives the answer to the convergence of $(*)$: since the class is closed we may as well consider $X_n$ as a Markov chain whose states are in $C_i$, and this (sub)Markov chain is recurrent irreducible.

If, however, the process starts from a transient (hence open) class, then I don't understand what the behaviour of $(*)$ is. With probability 1, the chain will end up in one of the recurrent classes, but I expect that the distribution of $(*)$ will depend on which class the chain lands in. Is there a general result/framework to understand the limit in this case, similar to the Ergodic theorem for dealing with the general case?

Comment: Each recurrent class $C_i$ has its own stationary distribution and can be considered as as single entity. Then you are left with a random walk on members of non-recurrent classes and with recurrent classes (as single states) being the absorbing states. Solve stationary distribution of this chain and use it to properly mix stationary distributions of recurrent classes.

Comment: @Raisin In (*) you don't want $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, rather $\sum_{i=1}^n  1_{\{X_i=v\}}$ for some state $v$.

Comment: @Byron I think $\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n P^i$ captures the essence succinctly.